# Exchange of functions and chain rule

Tags: calculus, functions

Let's say anything I have y=f(g(X))
Now can I write this as y=h(X) or would that be wrong. Because if I have an equation like y=sin(x^3) can I consider sin(x^3) as h(X) if yes. Then doesn't the meaning of the chain rule break down?

Comment: Then $\frac{dy}{dx}=h'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$, by chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

When $g:\>A\to B$ and $f:\>B\to C$ are functions then we can form their *composition*
$$f\circ g:\quad A\to C,\qquad x\mapsto f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\ .$$
The chain rule says something about the derivative of the composition, namely
$$(f\circ g)'(x)=f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\cdot g'(x)\ .$$
This rule refers to values of the derivatives of $f$, $g$, and $f\circ g$ at certain points, but also to the expressions resulting when $g$ and $f$ are given as explicit expressions, and $f\circ g$ is computed as the resulting expression.

At any time you are allowed to introduce an abbreviation $h$ for $f\circ g$.

Comment: What if you had f(g(x)) where is g(x) is not even continous can you differentiate f(g(x)) with respect to g(x)?? or is that undefined??

Answer (score 0):

Of Course you can write $sin(x^3)$ as a new function $h$ like this: $\ \ h:\Bbb R\to [{\pi \over 2}, {\pi \over 2}] \ \ , \ h(x)=sin(x^3)$.

It is not breaking the chain rule' meaning because if you want the derivative of $h$ you have to use the chain rule: $h'(x) = \bigl( sin(x^3) \bigr)'(x^3)' = 3x^2cos(x^3)$